# Unit testing Service class in Java Play Framework with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, playframework, mockito

I'm starting some testing using Mockito on some service classes I use for connecting to my data store. I now want to determine the best practice way writing tests for it.  The principle is for each entity there is a way to list, add, delete etc a row from the data store(mongo/mysql etc) for a specific entity.

Take this class that allows me to talk to my database that stores a list of companies

```
public class CompanyService extends Service{
    public CompanyService() {
        ...
    }

    public saveCompany(Company company) {
         ...
    }

     // get a list of all companies
    public List<Company> getCompanies() {

         List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();

         try {
             CompanyResult<Rows<String, String>> rows = db.query(....); 

             for (Row<String, String> row : rows.getResult()) {
                 companies.add(row.getColumns());
             }
         catch (Exception e){
            logger.warn("Error retrieving companies", e);
         }

    }

}
```

What exactly should I test in the getCompanies method and how can I use Mockito to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your System Under Test is the Company Service.  You want to test that, assuming all its dependencies/collaborators function properly, it functions properly.

The `db` object looks like the only dependency/collaborator you need to worry about within the  `getCompanies()` method.  Use Mockito to mock the call to `db.query()`

You could set up a test method like so:

```
@Test
public void testGetCompanies() {
  /*** Arraign ***/
  CompanyService cs = new CompanyService();

  // Setup mock db
  DB mockDb = mock(DB.class);

  // Setup fake results for query
  CompanyResult<Rows<String, String>> sampleResults = ... // build sample results here

  // Have query on mock return fake results
  when(db.query(/* match arguments */)).thenReturn(sampleResults);

  // Tell your System Under Test to use the mock collaborator
  cs.setDB(mockDb);

  /*** Act ***/
  CompanyResult<Rows<String, String>> results = cs.getCompanies();

  /*** Assert ***/
  ... // Test that results and sampleResults are effectively the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test how your code would work if the db query returned and empty result,null or if  row has null values or unexpected values.  You could mock the db class to return these values.  You could also mock the db class to throw an exception to see how your code could react.